# Where/How to install missing feature 'Mobile Browser View'

Tags: feature, mobile

I have this error in our staging SharePoint farm. I can remove the references, but I'd like to reinstall the feature since we have this feature installed on production.

> [MissingFeature] Database [STAGE_Farm_Content_Admin] has reference(s)
>   to a missing feature: Id = [d95c97f3-e528-4da2-ae9f-32b3535fbb59],
>   Name = [Mobile Browser View], Description = [Provide document library
>   and other lists in team site with mobile view for smartphone
>   browsers.], Install Location = [MBrowserRedirect]. The feature with Id
>   d95c97f3-e528-4da2-ae9f-32b3535fbb59 is referenced in the database
>   [STAGE_Farm_Content_Admin], but is not installed on the current farm.
>   The missing feature may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any
>   solution which contains the feature and restart upgrade if necessary.

If I look in '\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\FEATURES' I see the MBrowserRedirect folder with the feature inside.

Comment: Using powershell Install feature with id = `d95c97f3-e528-4da2-ae9f-32b3535fbb59` and use `-Force` attribute

Comment: The id didn't work but `Install-SPFeature "MBrowserRedirect" -Force` worked perfectly. Thank you. If you post an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Install-SPFeature` cmdlet try to `Force` install the feature.

The Install-SPFeature cmdlet installs a specific SPFeature by providing, in the Identity parameter, the relative path from the version-specific common FEATURES folder to the feature.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607825%28v=office.15%29.aspx